# Key generation in Digital Signature Algorithm

Tags: dsa

In DSA, one needs to generate two primes $p$ and $q$ such that $q$ is $256$-bit and $p$ is $3072$-bit and $p-1$ is a multiple of $q$.

Question: How to generate such $p$ and $q$.

Attempt: First, use a random number generator to generate $256$-bit number, say $q$. Then test whether it is a prime. If it is not, generate again until a prime is obtained.

After that, generate a random number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha$ is $(3072-256)=2816$ bits and $\alpha q +1$. Test whether $\alpha q+1$ is prime. If it is not, then generate $\alpha$ again. If yes, then we are done as we have two primes $p$ and $q$ which satisfy the conditions above.

Does the key generation above work?

Comment: The exact algorithm for generating the primes is specified in the DSS NIST FIPS 186-4 http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf

Comment: One issue with the proposed algorithm is that the $p$ generated will often be $3071$- bit rather than $3072$-bit, a stated requirement. Also, as pointed by Henrick Hellström, if you want DSA per the U.S. Department of Commerce's book, then [appendix A.1](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=40) is a must; also, following that procedure ensures the parameters are not cooked in some way; $p$ and $q$ essentially become [nothing-up-my-sleeve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number).

Answer (score 1):

As the comments are quite spot-on, I shall just reproduce them and say that you should just follow the relevant standard which is [FIPS 186-4 appendix A.1](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=40), which expands upon your intuition.

> The exact algorithm for generating the primes is specified in the DSS
>   [NIST FIPS 186-4 [(PDF)]](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf)  –
>   Henrick Hellström

and

> One issue with the proposed algorithm is that the p generated will
>   often be 3071- bit rather than 3072-bit, a stated requirement. Also,
>   as pointed by Henrick Hellström, if you want DSA per the U.S.
>   Department of Commerce's book, then [appendix A.1 [(PDF)]](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=40) is a
>   must; also, following that procedure ensures the parameters are not
>   cooked in some way; p and q essentially become
>   [nothing-up-my-sleeve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number). – fgrieu