# DSA: How to calculate 224-bit $q$ for 2048-bit $p$

Tags: dsa, prime-numbers

$p$ is a 2048 bit prime number

$q$ is a 224 bit prime number

I know that $q$ is a prime divisor of $p-1$, thus $p=1 \bmod q$ but I couldn't write efficient code to calculate this.

- I can calculate 2048 bit prime $p$, but how to find $q$ efficiently?

Currently what I am doing is generating 224-bit primes and checking whether they are dividing $p-1$ or not but it takes forever...

Comment: Does [Key generation in Digital Signature Algorithm](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20290/key-generation-in-digital-signature-algorithm) help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can calculate 2048 bit prime $p$, but how to find $q$ efficiently?

You're doing things in the wrong order.

Instead, you pick a 224 bit $q$, and then such for a 2048 bit prime of the form $p = kq + 1$ (for some integer $k$).

This can be done with essentially the same amount of effort as finding a 2048 bit prime (without constraints), and directly answers the problem, as such a $p, q$ pair guarantees that $p \equiv kq + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod q$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Currently i am generating prime numbers with this : generate random number given n bits and test whether its prime or not with isPrime function.So how should i modify this to find p ? Am i going to multiply q  some k s,(what should be k  trials ??)  then add 1 and check until it is prime ? I mean what should be the range of ks that i am going to test in a loop

Comment: I guess i couldnt understand since my code still takes forever

Comment: @doggodonger: are you adding one to $k$, or one to $p$?  Adding one to $k$ (or equivalently, adding $q$ to $p$) is the correct thing.  If you add 1 to $p$, then your initial $p$ will be of the form $kq+1$; the ones after the first won't be